# Android - get values from customListview

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, custom-lists

I have an edittext in each row of my customlistview where users enter the number of quantity of products(in adapter.java page).Other values are set from database.I want to get values of edittext in each row on button (Activity.java)click.I tried using sharedpreference.But got null pointer exception in line  **Bundle qbdl=new Bundle();**.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class add2cart extends Activity{
public static ListView adlstvw;
ListView adlstvw;
Button btn,remove_btn;
SQLiteDatabase mydb;
public static String sme,dl;
public String bl;
SharedPreferences sp;
SharedPreferences.Editor spe;
String qty=CartAdapter.s2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add2crt);
    adlstvw=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstvw_add2crt);
    btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.place_order);

    Bundle bundl = getIntent().getExtras();
    Bundle bodl=getIntent().getExtras();

    if (bodl!=null) {
        dl=bodl.getString("dts");
    }


    if (bundl != null) {
     sme= bundl.getString("dtls");

     }


    mydb=add2cart.this.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS add2cart(usr TEXT,img BLOB,pnme TEXT,prate NUMERIC,pqty NUMERIC,ptotl NUMERIC)");
    Cursor cr = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM add2cart WHERE usr='"+sme+"' OR usr='"+dl+"'", null);
    String [] pname = new String[cr.getCount()];
    String [] price = new String[cr.getCount()];

    int i = 0;
    while(cr.moveToNext())
    {
        String name = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pnme"));
        String prprice = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("prate"));
        pname[i] = name;
        price[i] = prprice;
        i++;
    }
    CartAdapter cart=new CartAdapter(this,pname,price);
    adlstvw.setAdapter(cart);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            /////////////////////////
             String qty=sp.getString("quty", null);


            Intent in=new Intent(add2cart.this,buy_ltr.class); 
            Bundle bod=new Bundle();
            Bundle bndl = new Bundle();

             ////////////////
            Bundle qbdl=new Bundle();
            qbdl.putString("prqt", qty);
            in.putExtras(qbdl);


            bod.putString("kew", dl);
            in.putExtras(bod);
            bndl.putString("som",sme); 
            in.putExtras(bndl);
            startActivity(in);

        }
    });

}

}
```

**CartAdapter.java**

```
public class CartAdapter extends BaseAdapter{


private final String[] pname;
private final String[] price;
String s2;
String abc=add2cart.sme;
String cba=add2cart.dl;
private Context cntxt;

 /////////////////
SharedPreferences sp;
SharedPreferences.Editor spe;
 /////////////////

 public CartAdapter(Context c,String [] pname,String [] price)
 {

     cntxt=c;
     this.pname=pname;
     this.price=price;
 }
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return pname.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View List;
    LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)cntxt.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView==null) {
List=new View(cntxt);
List=mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add2crt_sub,parent, false);

 }
else {
List=(View)convertView;
}

Button button=(Button)List.findViewById(R.id.remove);
button.setTag(position);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


        int position = (Integer)v.getTag();
        SQLiteDatabase mydb=cntxt.openOrCreateDatabase("addcart",Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        String pnam = pname[position];

        mydb.execSQL("DELETE FROM add2cart WHERE pnme ='"+pnam+"' AND (usr='"+cba+"' OR usr='"+abc+"')");

        Cursor cr = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM add2cart WHERE usr='"+cba+"' OR usr='"+abc+"'", null);
        String [] pname = new String[cr.getCount()];
        String [] price = new String[cr.getCount()]; 


        int i = 0;
        while(cr.moveToNext())
        {
            String name = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("pnme"));
            String prprice = cr.getString(cr.getColumnIndex("prate"));
            pname[i] = name;
            price[i] = prprice;
            i++;
        }
        CartAdapter cart=new CartAdapter(cntxt,pname,price);
        add2cart.adlstvw.setAdapter(cart);

    }
    });
 TextView nametxt=(TextView)List.findViewById(R.id.prdt_nme);
 final TextView pricetxt=(TextView)List.findViewById(R.id.prdt_rate);
 final TextView totltxt=(TextView)List.findViewById(R.id.prdt_totl);
 final EditText edittext=(EditText)List.findViewById(R.id.prdt_qnty);
 edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


          /////////////////////////
        sp=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(cntxt);
        spe=sp.edit();
        String s1=pricetxt.getText().toString();
        s2=edittext.getText().toString();
        spe.putString("quty", s2);


        int i1=0;
        if (!s1.equals("")) {
        i1=Integer.parseInt(s1);    
        }

        int i2=0;
        if (!s2.equals("")) {
        i2=Integer.parseInt(s2);    
        }

        int res=i1*i2;
        totltxt.setText(Integer.toString(res));


    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});

 nametxt.setText(pname[position].toString());
 pricetxt.setText(price[position]);

    return List;
}


}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
02-09 04:13:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(8978): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 04:13:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(8978): Process: com.power.it.solar, PID: 8978
02-09 04:13:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(8978): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-09 04:13:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):     at com.power.it.solar.add2cart$1.onClick(add2cart.java:76)
02-09 04:13:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4424)
02-09 04:13:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18383)
02-09 04:13:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-09 04:13:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-09 04:13:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-09 04:13:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-09 04:13:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 04:13:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-09 04:13:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-09 04:13:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-09 04:13:50.705: E/AndroidRuntime(8978):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[image]

Comment: which value you want to access on `btn` button click?

Comment: name in adepter is not meaningful so please let me know which variable hold quantity value?

Comment: use `SharedPreferences` for setting value on Button click

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK    
But.how to get values from every row?

Comment: simply save value in SharedPreferences for every row and get on button

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I tried using shared preference.But got a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
et.setTag("tagname");
```

method on your edittext view in your adapter then get the value on your button listener by tag like:

```
if(v.gettag().equals("tagname")){
//Write your code
}
```